# Firefox extension for site-maintenance (link checking)

Tags: firefox-addon

Are there any Firefox extensions for site-maintenance, specifically, for checking if all the links on the site are working?

I'm currently using the LinkChecker addon, which works wonderfully, except that it can only do one page at a time.

I'm looking for something more automated, which will check each link, then go down the link and check all links within the page as well. This will continue on to check all the links on the page.

Anything that exists which can do this?

Answer (score 1):

For checking links you could try the [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink?) and I do believe it allows recursive checking.

The [Web Developer Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) has a link checker that uses the W3C service and also provides several other tools for checking and validating web sites.

Comment: Are any of these solutions available to intranet sites? The reasons is that the site I'm trying to maintain is hosted on an intranet environment, so it probably won't be available outside the network.

Comment: All the W3C tools are open source and can be downloaded. I think what others have done in your position is download the tools and set them up on the intranet. Here is a link to installing the W3C link checker locally. http://validator.w3.org/docs/checklink#install